# Models that train on Mean Absolute Error or similar?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I'm trying to do time series prediction and I'm interested in training on MAE or other custom loss functions. For my problem I'd prefer having errors of {0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10} as supposed to {5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5} so that I am occasionally hitting i.e. getting error=0. I tried rlm() in R and that saw an improvement versus lm() since I'm guessing it's giving less conservative projections and not worried about missing on outliers, so for that reason I'd like to try more models that use MAE or allow for custom loss function. Linear models have been working best so far, but I'm interested in suggestions on any models that might help. Thanks

Comment: What interval are you calculating when you use the linear model (is it for example, an interval for the mean - the usual regression confidence interval instead of a regression prediction interval? Please be clearer about what you did.

Comment: I'm not calculating an interval. I'm training a linear model and predicting on data in the future and the resulting prediction ends up just being very close to the mean of the training data. I'm hoping to get predictions that can have more variance to them so have more hits and misses on data in the future rather than just being always close to the mean so was wondering if there are models that could be useful for this.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean. Please be considerably more explicit.

Comment: The more accurate your predictions, the more they will approximate observed values rather than sticking close to the mean.  So I am not sure what you need other than a more accurate model.  I doubt that you would value highly varying predictions for their own sake; if you did you could simply add some random jitter.

Comment: @Glen_b For example, if you are trying to predict two stock prices, it might be the case that having prediction errors of 0 and 10 are more favorable than prediction errors of 5 and 5. In the first case the model hits and misses often where in the second case the model is sort of close for all points.

Comment: @rolando2 I think how I should have phrased it is that I highly value instances of small error. Perhaps I will look into training on a different loss function. Thank you for the jitter suggestion

Comment: @Brian L Thanks -- the example you give helps. What you're getting at there is that your loss function is not well modelled by using an $L^2$ norm. So the problem is not one of increasing the variance but of correctly defining what you want your predictions to do. For example if you want to predict close to the most likely value, don't use minimum mean square error predictions. If you describe your problem in more detail in your question - along with what properties you want your predictions to have (i.e. what you want to do well at) you will be likely to get better advice.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, that clears things up. I edited the question to explain my problem more.

Comment: Want more variance in your predictions?  Just add independent random noise.  I hope that makes it clear that increasing variance prediction will not cure overfitting or whatever else might ail your models.  Unduly low prediction variance may be a symptom of a problem, but it cannot possibly be the underlying cause of a problem.

Comment: @whuber I'm just wondering if there are any linear models that train on MAE or allow for custom loss function. I think my question may have been confusing because I'm basically just trying to use a different loss function but don't know how to do that with a simple model like a linear model. I tried adding random noise but it makes MAE worse.

Comment: There are models and even software for such loss functions.  "Quantile regression" is one example (which might be irrelevant in your case: I mention it only to show that such things exist).  Why not make some wholesale edits to your question so it focuses on that issue rather than prediction variance?

Comment: @whuber Ok I gave it another shot

Comment: @BrianL:  Can you spell out what MAE stands for? You may get a wider audience that way.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to linear models? Your reasoning doesn't seem adequate. And why only simple models? I don't see why you couldn't write a linear regression that optimizes mean absolute error though.

Comment: @AnscombesGimlet I tried other models like gbm but was doing much better with a linear model. Why doesn't that seem adequate. Do you know any resources for writing a linear regression?

Comment: Gradient boosting typically only outperforms other time series methods if you're working with hundreds/thousands of series. If you edit your question to include non-linear and linear methods, I think I know of a solution that won't require you to write your own method.

Comment: @AnscombesGimlet Ok just did

Comment: probably using SQRT as loss function would help you and the closer the exponent is to 0, the more you ignore hi losses

Answer (score 0):

Since this is time-series, you may want to try the ETS framework. Some models are linear, others not. The R forecast package has an ets function in which you can optimize via a number of criterion, including MAE and it will pick the best model for your data in that framework.